# UserForm ComboBox

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, userform

I have a UserForm that has one ComboBox and a TextBox. The TextBox needs to do a vlookup for the value of the ComboBox but ONLY if that value exists in the list, if not, I want nothing to appear in the TextBox so the user can enter new information.

This is how far I have got:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
If cbocolor.Value <> "" Then

Dim evalStr As String
Dim check As Variant
evalStr = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cbocolor.Value,        worksheets("CONTACTS").Range("allcontacts"), 2, False)
check = Evaluate(evalStr)
If VarType(check) = vbError Then
TextBox1.Value = "Enter new info"

Else
var1 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cbocolor.Value,      Worksheets("CONTACTS").Range("allcontacts"), 2, False)
TextBox1.Value = var1



End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it all with one line:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
    If cbocolor.value <> "" Then

        TextBox1.value = WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.VLookup(cbocolor.value, _
           Worksheets("CONTACTS").Range("allcontacts"), 2, False), "Enter New Info")

   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I CANT THANK YOU ENOUGH,I knew it was ridiculous easy, and i knew i was thinking too hard about it. Thanks so much.

Comment: @CORNAKI YOU DEFINITELY LIKE THE CAPS. :) You are welcome.  If you are inclined would you mark it as correct.

Comment: Can i ask a question, just to understand better. What i see from your answer is - if there is an error then do 'first thing' and ifnot then do 'second thing' - But your code is doing the opposite. It works perfect but i would like to understand. Thanks

Comment: @CORNAKI With IFError() it is the opposite.  It tries to do the first thing, if an error results then it does the second thing otherwise it returns the value found in the first formula.

Comment: Also with the Vlookup function notice I have`application` in front not `worksheetfunction`,  This allows a #N/A to be returned.  With the `WorksheetFunction` it does not allow the #N/A to return as a value and stops the code.

Comment: great stuff appreciate it!

Comment: you took care of this a long time ago, and i appreciate it, BUT, i just nticed it is doing something weird that is causing problems. It always gives a zero value into the cell if the vlookup doesn't find anything. It doesn't even entre the "enter new info" just a zero